# Package is not added after instantiating in Julia

Tags: installation, package, julia, development-environment

I received a project environment from a colleague which contains the Manifest.toml, Project.toml and script.jl files. I tried to install the dependency for this project, which is just the *ArgParse* package, by running:

```
julia --project=. -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.instantiate()'
```

Then, when I start a julia session and try to load this package I get the message that the package is in General registry and if I want to add it:

```
julia --project=.
julia> using ArgParse
 │ Package ArgParse not found, but a package named ArgParse is available from a registry. 
 │ Install package?
 │   (my-env) pkg> add ArgParse 
 └ (y/n/o) [y]:
```

I thought that by running *Pkg.instantiate()* all dependencies would be added so that one could start using a project, rather than manually adding these dependencies. Am I missing anything? Thank you.

Comment: hmmm.. that's strange.. are you using the same Julia version? If not you can try `Pkg.resolve()`. Another option is to manually enter the project environment by typing `Pkg.activate(".")` and then `Pkg.instantiate()` from the Julia prompt instead of the terminal

Comment: It seems like you are doing this fine. Most likely you have mixed up some directories or Julia versions or made some typo. Try ` Pkg.status()` to see at which project folder you are. Moreover if after running ` Pkg.status()`  you will just see `ArgParse` without version number it means that only `Project.toml` got loaded while when you see the version number it means that the `Manifest.toml` got loaded as well

Comment: The status is as follows: 
```Status `/project/Project.toml`
  [c7e460c6] ArgParse
Warning The project dependencies or compat requirements have changed since the manifest was last resolved. It is recommended to `Pkg.resolve()` or consider `Pkg.update()` if necessary```.   The following line solved the issue: `julia --project=. -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.resolve();Pkg.instantiate()'`. Now I can load the Argparse package.